# Is there a succint way to test exit status of a set of commands in bash?

Tags: bash, rsync, exitstatus

I have a simple script to pull data from a remote server as a process generates it using `rsync`:

```
while :
do
    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/foo* ./

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/bar* ./

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/baz* ./

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/qux* ./

    sleep 900 #wait 15 minutes, try again
done
```

If there are no files, `rsync` returns exit status 12 (apparently).  In the event that **none** of the above calls to `rsync` finds any data, I would like to break from the loop (the process generating the data probably exited).  To alleviate any confusion, I do **not** want to break from the loop if even 1 of the `rsync` processes succeed.

Is there a succinct way to do that in bash?

Comment: Exit status 12 appears to be related to errors in the protocol data stream. Do you want to exit the loop on *any* nonzero exit status (from all the `rsync` processes)?

Comment: @ezod -- I think any non-zero exit status is good enough for me to break on (but only if they are all non-zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way counts the number of fails due to no file.

```
while :
do
    nofile=0

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/foo* ./
    (( $? == 12 )) && let nofile++

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/bar* ./
    (( $? == 12 )) && let nofile++

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/baz* ./
    (( $? == 12 )) && let nofile++

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/qux* ./
    (( $? == 12 )) && let nofile++

    # if all failed due to "no files", break the loop
    if (( $nofile == 4 )); then break; fi

    sleep 900 #wait 15 minutes, try again
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by adding up the return values, so that if they all return 12, the sum is 48:

```
while :
do
    rc=0
    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/foo* ./
    let rc+=$?

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/bar* ./
    let rc+=$?

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/baz* ./
    let rc+=$?

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/qux* ./
    let rc+=$?

    if [[ $rc == 48 ]]; then  # 48 = 4 * 12
         break;
    fi

    sleep 900 #wait 15 minutes, try again
done
```

Note that this may suffer if you get another combination of return codes sums to 48, i.e. 0 + 0 + 12 + 36

Comment: I thought about something like this.  I don't want to rely on it actually using exit status 12 though ... This is more a boolean sort of thing.  I suppose I could do something like `rsync ... || let rc+=1` and then `if [[ $rc -eq 4 ]]; then break; fi` ...

Comment: good idea, but to avoid having to worry about other combinations, why not just append the $rc values to each other and then use `case $rc in *[1-9]* ) print "found non-zero exit code=$rc, can't continue" ; exit 1 ;; esac`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Just add them and break if the sum is non-zero.

Comment: @shellter -- No, I only want to exit if they *all* fail.  If 1 fails, I want to continue.

Comment: ok, then invert the test. `case $rc in *0* ) echo "at least one did not fail, keep running" ;; * ) print "no zeros found, must have all failed, quiting" ; exit 1 ;; esac` . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the other answers, I think this is the cleanest way I can do it so far ...

```
while :
do
    do_continue=0

    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/foo* ./ && do_continue=1
    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/bar* ./ && do_continue=1
    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/baz* ./ && do_continue=1
    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/qux* ./ && do_continue=1

    if [[ $do_continue == 0 ]]; then 
       break
    fi

    sleep 900 #wait 15 minutes, try again
done
```

which could be refactored more to remove the break statement and associated conditional test:

```
do_continue=1
while [ do_continue -eq 1 ]; do
    do_continue=0
    rsync -avz --remove-source-files -e ssh me@remote:path/to/foo* ./ && do_continue=1
    #...
    sleep 900
done
```